# Push multiple series in highcharts from JSON source

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I want to make a line chart with multiple series. The source is JSON code. It works for one serie, but with multiple it does not work. SOLVED.

Next thing is that I want to push the datalabels from JSON.

EDITED: This is my javascript:

```
function slowips(target){

var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: target,
        type: 'line',
        borderColor: '#0072C6',
        borderWidth: 3
    },
    title: {
            text: ''
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'MS'
        },


    },
    exporting: {
     enabled: false
    },  
    credits: {
     enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'category'
        },
        minorTickLength: 0,
        tickLength: 0
    },
     plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    color: '#0072C6',
                    align: 'center',


                    style: {
                        fontSize: '11px',

                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',

                    },
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y;
                    },

                },
                animation: false,
                enableMouseTracking: false

            }
        },
    series: [{}]
};


$.getJSON('graphs/slowips.php', function(data) {
    options.series = data; 
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
}
```

EDITED: This is an example of the JSON data that is being loaded:

```
[
{"name":"s1","data":[36,52,46,94,45,31,31,31,30,29,32,35,151,137,161,146,29,42,52,155,168,146,141,165,140,145,37,30,40,151]}, 
{"name":"s2","data":[35,41,51,95,31,30,28,31,32,28,32,27,39,33,52,42,45,53,45,37,42,45,47,47,39,29,35,30,39,39]}, 
{"name":"s3","data":[34,41,43,90,60,117,32,27,28,26,28,24,39,33,49,39,39,43,46,30,41,44,48,50,43,25,33,25,35,46]}, 
{"name":"s4","data":[23,34,24,76,13,16,16,15,18,15,17,21,23,20,34,25,14,24,26,23,36,50,31,36,21,14,17,17,22,29]}, 
{"name":"s5","data":[22,37,31,88,22,15,14,23,18,14,14,25,17,19,35,20,25,23,31,23,29,26,27,25,18,15,14,12,24,29]}
]
```

However this does not give me the expected result. What am I doing wrong? I want the graph to contain 5 lines out of the 5 series provided. SOLVED.

Comment: I advice to familair with figure of json, which should be used http://jsfiddle.net/umY65/ so you need to parse your json to correct form.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I got that working, see the edited code above. Last thing is that I want to push the labels on the x axis from JSON. How should my JSON look? Please help

Comment: You can modify xAxis properties or replace each point with array [x,y]

Comment: Ok thanks. That worked. What if I want the X axis labels to be date/time? Using for example [Date.UTC(2014,  9, 27),2] makes it not render the graph.

Comment: Please set type as datetime on xAxis, then use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats / http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter and http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat.